# append text to file. adding text to specified txt file.

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, argparse

Im trying to add text to a config file that from a -a switch.
The rest of the code does work but not sure who to call the select config file and write a new file to backup into it.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copy multiple Files from a specified data file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--configfile', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', default="/home/admin/Documents/backup/",help='Choose location to store files')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--addfile', help='Choose a file to add to list')

def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        # Read in date from config.dat
        data = open(data)
        # Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        # Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("Config file not found")
        print ("Config File not found")

def add_to_file():
    try:
        f = open('configfile','r')
        f.read()
        addto = f.write('addfile')
        f.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
            pass**
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
read = read_config(args['configfile'])
add = add_to_file(args['addfile'])
```

When i run this i get an error such as the following:

```
    add = add_to_file(args['addfile'])
TypeError: add_to_file() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong with this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

The error has the problem in it:

```
add_to_file() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

`add_to_file` doesn't take any args, but you're passing it one.

Edit: There are a few things wrong here, but my original answer is your immediate hurdle:

1. f.write doesn't return anything, there's no need to assign it.
2. You never close the file in read_config.
3. To append to the file, you need to open it with `a` mode, like this: `open('configfile', 'a')` instead of `r` mode
4. You're over-indented in your except block. Also I'm not even sure what pass** does. You should probably just let it raise.
5. I'm not entirely sure what the code is trying to accomplish here. It looks like read_config will read a list of files, then copy them to dest. I get that. But then what does `add_to_file` do? Add more files to the config that will be copied in a subsequent run of read_config?

For #2, consider using a context manager. It will handle closing the file for you. It looks like this:

```
with open('some_file.txt', 'r'):
    do_some_stuff()
```

The above sample will handle opening and closing the file, even if there are exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  
I changed to the following:

def addtofile(test):
    try:
        with open('config.dat', 'a') as file:
            file.write(test + "\n")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("error message")

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
read = read_config(args['configfile'])
add = addtofile(args['add'])

shutil.SameFileError: 'backup/test.dat' and '/home/admin/Documents/backup/test.dat' are the same file